# Periodically trigger redrawing custom view

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, drawing, custom-view

I'm writing a Timer-App as my first Cocoa-Application using Swift and ran into a Problem. I use a custom view to display the remaining time. It works fine, but when I hit one of the buttons the redrawing stops until I release the button. I guess it's something about the way I trigger the drawing of the view using NSTimer which seems to interfere with the run-loop.

When the start button is hit, the current time is recorded.

```
startTime = NSDate()
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.05, target: self,
            selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

In the update method the elapsed time is calculated and stored in a property which is monitored by KVO in the View Controller. Where the view is told to redraw.

```
timerView.needsDisplay = true
```

What's the proper way to update a view?

[image: Custom View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add your timer to the mainRunLoop for mode NSRunLoopCommonModes:

```
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
```

Comment: If the downvoter knows a different way to accomplish it why don't you post your answer or just comment the reason of it?

Comment: BTW I've already tested it with Xcode 6.1.1 and Xcode 6.3 and it works with both of them

Comment: Not a downvoter, but it will be wasteful if system is not able to redraw at that speed. Much better is to listen for V-Sync.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the button an animation occurs which stops all other animations/drawings on the main thread.

Why don't you run your timer async on a background thread so it won't be affected by main thread interactions.

Have a look at `NSOperation`

Comment: Can you provide a little code sample showing how to implement it

Comment: The secret to making apps snappy is to offload as much unnecessary work to the background as possible, and in this respect, the modern Cocoa developer has two options: Grand Central Dispatch and NSOperation. http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/ - you can also find plenty of tutorials on how to implement NSOperation. There's even an Apple Sessions in DevCenter about it.

Comment: can you modify this sample and show us how it would look like ?

Comment: The sample you uploaded doesn't contain any code to modify.

Comment: What you mean? The code is using my method not the one suggested by you

Comment: I don't see any drawing occurring the sample I downloaded from the dropbox link.

Comment: I can provide one if you think it will make any difference

Comment: Can you show us how to use NSOperation modifying my sample?